# Slug getting cut laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently I have staging link of my laravel project

`http://**.***.**.***/project-name/cart`

If project accessed like this `http://**.***.**.***/project-name/cart`

It's accessible, but if you access it like

`http://**.***.**.***/project-name/cart/`

when slash exists after cart, it redirects to `http://**.***.**.***/cart`

which turns *not found*

Is this related with Htaccess?

Btw, here's my htaccess code

```
 #<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
 #  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
#  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
#  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
#  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
#  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
#  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
#  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
#  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
#  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
#  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
 #
 #  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
 #  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
 #  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
 #  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
 #  Header append Vary User-Agent
 #</IfModule>
 #
 ### EXPIRES CACHING ##
 #<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 #  ExpiresActive On
 #
 #  # Images
 #  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
 #  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
 #  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
 #  ExpiresByType image/webp "access plus 1 year"
 #  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
 #  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
 #
 #  # Video
 #  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 year"
 #  ExpiresByType video/mpeg "access plus 1 year"
 #
 #  # CSS, JavaScript
 #  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
 #  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
 #  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
 #
 #  # Others
 #  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
 #  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
 #</IfModule>
 ### EXPIRES CACHING ##

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

 #    # Force Https
 #    RewriteEngine On
 #    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 #    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
 #
 #    # Force www
 #    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
 #    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
 </IfModule>

 # Check if mod is installed. If not, you can try to comment the condition
 <IfModule mod_php7.c>
   php_value post_max_size 200M
   php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
   php_value memory_limit 300M
   php_value max_execution_time 259200
   php_value max_input_time 259200
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    Options -Indexes
        </IfModule>
  <FilesMatch "^\.">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file located?

Answer (score 0):

If your `.htaccess` file is in the `/project-name` subdirectory and not the document root then yes, the problem is related to `.htaccess`. Specifically, the following rule that removes the trailing slash:

> ```
> # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
> ```

If the `.htaccess` file is in the `/project-name` subdirectory then the `$1` backreference will exclude the subdirectory since the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is relative to the current filesystem directory.

You'll need to capture the URL-path (less the trailing slash) from the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead, which contains the full root-relative URL-path.

Try the following instead:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$
RewriteRule /$ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

Note the `%1` backreference in the *substitution* string, instead of `$1` as you had before. Backreferences of the form `%n` related to the preceding *conditions*.

Since this is a 301 (permanent) redirect you will need to clear your browser cache before testing. Preferably test with 302 (temporary) redirects.